# ¿Que lenguaje de Programación Funcional, tiene mayor soporte en ambiente windows?

Tags: haskell, programación-funcional, scala

Que lenguaje de programación funcional, me sugieren aprender, sabiendo que mis conocimientos son entorno a **Windows, .NET MVC, C#, javascript**, les comento para no alejarme mucho de mi ambiente, estoy muy interesado en las inteligencias artificiales, pero no se por donde empezar y evitar que la curva de aprendizaje sea muy grande.

Que lenguaje de programación funcional tiene mayor soporte en ambiente windows ?

Comment: Hola tu pregunta esta alejada de una respuesta en concreto porque depende mucho los gustos y experiencia del usuario, aunque una alternativa sin salir de .NET podria ser  F# http://fsharp.org

Comment: Pues pienso que al colocar que mis entornos **Windows, .NET MVC, C#, JavaScript** aporta una idea sobre mis gustos y experiencia. Y como comento es para entrar en el mundo de las IA's. sin hacer largo el proceso. Gracias por tu respuesta,

Comment: No creo que estemos hablando de gustos personales. Es más saber los motivos por los que quieres la programación funcional, ya que no tiene una relación directa con la inteligencia artificial, ni tampoco es que sea el paradigma más usado en windows. Con C# o javascript también puedes hacer programas funcionales, pero en las etiquetas pones haskell y scala como si ya estuvieras predispuesto a estos lenguajes. Con tu bagaje, lo tuyo sería meterte con F# para .Net. Pero si te interesa mucho la AI, deberías empezar por un lenguaje *lispoide* como [racket](http://racket-lang.org/).

Comment: en windows que versión? 95? NT? Cuales son para tí los lenguajes de programación funcional?